# Livepatch requires an internet connection

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Livepatch console reports that:

```
livepatch requires an internet connection
```

However, all connections (LAN/WAN) are operating normally, with the necessary ports on `ufw` open. This is a new install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: What is your "default route"? `ip route`.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: Having identical behavior on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, but doing a sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose states the server check-in did succeed, no live patchers were needed, and that the kernel is unsupported... so maybe it's just a poor error message.  Did @waltinator 's diagnostic and see the machine's IP address, network address, and when I tried a ping (to say 1.1.1.1) got a 4ms response.

Comment: // , Same issue.

Comment: // , As it happens, the error should read, "Livepatch requires an ipv6 internet connection".

Answer (score 1):

// , Livepatch needs ipv6 for who knows what silly reason. So you gotta turn off your damn VPN.

VPN==sadness

```
vault-scanner[master]$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable 1111069ffffffffff57fa628acaaaaac
2020/10/27 10:56:13 error executing enable: cannot enable machine: cannot send request: Post https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine-tokens: dial tcp: lookup livepatch.canonical.com on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: connect: network is unreachable
vault-scanner1[master]$
```

No VPN==happy

```
vault-scanner1[master]$ sudo canonical-livepatch enable 1111069ffffffffff57fa628acaaaaac
Successfully enabled device. Using machine-token: 1111069ffffffffff57fa628acaaaaac
vault-scanner[master]$
```

It'll be the same result in the GUI console, but I can't be arsed to post screenshots since this'll probably just get deleted anyway.

Comment: Well, THAT´s super annoying. ~:-| Especially since here it is >2 years later and someone must think that's a feature, rather than a bug.